# Can I use transactions in order to make sure the result of my query is exactly what I want after stoping the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

So, I have a select query that it should return the customers that have more than 3 purchases along with their purchases. For example, if customer A has 4 purchases, the result for my query should include this customer and his transactions (4 rows for his 4 purchases). But customer B who has 2 purchases, should not be included in the result, nor his 2 transactions.  My query takes too long and I need to stop my query(kill it) in the middle of its run. However, I want the result of the query to have the requirement (i.e. the 3 purchase limit). In other words, I want those customers that their transactions are inserted in the result, but due to the halt, the number of transactions is not 3 yet, to be removed from the result to maintain the requirement. I am thinking about using transactions. But I am not sure how can I do this. This example shows what I want. Imagine this is my original table:

```
customer_id   purchase_price
  1            200
  1            300
  1            230
  1            340
  2            55
  2            56
  3            566
  3            45
  3            666
```

The desired result of my query if it terminates without interrupt should be something like this:

```
     customer_id   purchase_price
  1            200
  1            300
  1            230
  1            340
  3            566
  3            45
  3            666
```

But not this:

```
   customer_id   purchase_price
  1            200
  1            300
  1            230
  1            340
  3            566
  3            45
```

In other words, in case that the program stopped before termination (program stopped before it inserts every transactions for customer 3) , I should get something like this:

```
  customer_id   purchase_price
  1            200
  1            300
  1            230
  1            340
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results are helpful as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support the ANSI standard window functions.  You can do directly what you want using them:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by customer) as cnt
      from transactions t
     ) t
where cnt >= 20;
```

MySQL does not support these functions.  Instead, you can do:

```
select t.*
from transactions t join
     (select customer, count(*) 
      from transactions
      group by customer
      having count(*) >= 20
     ) tc
     on tc.customer = t.customer;
```

Comment: Is this mysql query?

Comment: I am wondering if you understood what I want. I want when I kill the query(force it to stop) the result includes only customers and their transactions that has at least 3 purchases (This is the tricky part. The customers will be in the result, but their transactions might not if I stop the query)

Comment: @HimanUCC . . . When you force a query to stop, the changes are rolled back.  Those are the ACID properties of databases.

Comment: But I run this query and I did not get the result I want. All customers were those customers that I wanted, but for some of them, there were not 3 transactions in the result because I forced the query to stop.